# Buttons suddenly has stopped working inside gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Canvas... and inside canvas I have two `gameobjects`. When I run the game first `gameobjects` buttons work fine. But when switch over to the second `gameobject` their buttons suddenly not working.The canvas includes `EventSystem` and `InputModule`.I am switching between gameobjects by script...and that script added to the Canvas.

Comment: Can you post your script? The issue might be caused by it.

Comment: The script and some screenshots would help the answers a lot :)